Output all unique combos for a list of items
For example, given an input array of [A,B,C,D] the output should be:
[A,B,C,D,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,ABC,ABD,ACD,BCD,ABCD]
Most the answers I’ve found deal with combing multiple lists together or include ouputs such as ‘AA’ or both ‘AB’ & ‘BA’ - which I do not want.
I’d also like the formula to scale up or down dynamically based on the size of the input array and filter out blanks so I can simply point it at, say “A1:A” then as I add or remove values to the A column my list of unique combos updates.
For example, if the input array was [A,B,C] the output would be [A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC].

can the input array have duplicates?

If it did I’d want to make sure the formula is only looking at the unique values in the input array. So if I accidentally had [A,B,C,D,A] as the input array that should be treated as [A,B,C,D] @z..


Here's one approach but it can accommodate a max 18 count of the input array & post that its reaching the lambda calculation limit :
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A:A,1)), Δ,tocol(byrow(index(int(mod(sequence(2^rows(Σ))/2^sequence(1,rows(Σ),0),2))),lambda(Λ,join(,filter(torow(Σ),Λ)))),3),
 sort(Δ,len(Δ),1,1,1))


backend_matrix logic:


Exactly what I needed—thank you!
Now for the fun part of unravelling your formula so I can understand how you solved :)

can you elaborate on what's going on within the mod function? I'm following up until you divide by 2^sequence, etc.

https://i.imgur.com/LXjo7Eh.png hopefully this should give a visual picture of how the backend matrix is created. I have formulas in B2, C1, C2 alongside the formulatext

Super clear—thank you!

EDIT: Formula that works up to n=23 (8,388,608 rows)
Since there seems to be a 10M limit on the size of the virtual arrays as well, I slightly tweaked the previous formula to generate the tree in a single column rather than 3 (which turned out to be a lot easier than I thought). This formula now works up to n=23, i.e. 8,388,608 rows.
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
    list,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),
    res,MID(REDUCE(,list,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;a&","&c})),2,9^9),
    QUERY(SORT(res,LEN(res),1,1,1),"offset 1",0)))


EDIT: Alternative approach
I tried to solve this with a different approach using a REDUCE based binary tree:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
    list,TOCOL(A:A,1),
    iter,REDUCE({1,"",INDEX(list,1)},SEQUENCE(ROWS(list)-1,1,2),LAMBDA(a,i,LET(
           prev,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(a,2,3),INDEX(a,,1)=i-1),
           VSTACK(a,HSTACK(IF(SEQUENCE(2^(i-1)),i),VSTACK(prev,REGEXREPLACE(prev&","&INDEX(list,i),"^,",))))))),
    res,QUERY(TOCOL(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(iter,2,3),INDEX(iter,,1)=ROWS(list))),"offset 1",0),
    SORT(res,LEN(res),1,1,1)))


It's essentially performing n iterations, where n is the number of items in the list, and at each iterations it explore the two possibilites: include or exclude the current item.

The last iteration contains all the possible combinations.
Given that the maximum number of cells a spreadsheet can have is 10,000,000, the theoretical maximum number of items the formula can handle is 23 which would require 2^23 = 8,388,608 cells but on my machine it works up to 21 items, if I go beyond that the sheet crashes.

Another solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
    list,TOCOL(UNIQUE(A:A),1),size,ROWS(list),idx,SEQUENCE(size),
    binary_array,SEQUENCE(1,size)*REGEXEXTRACT(BASE(SEQUENCE(2^size-1),2,size),REPT("(.)",size)),
    result,BYROW(VLOOKUP(binary_array,{idx,list},2,0),LAMBDA(row,JOIN(,IFNA(row)))),
    SORT(result,LEN(result),1,result,1)))


Let n be the number of values in the list. The formula creates a binary array of size 2^n-1 x n and it multiplies each of its rows by the 1 x n array of values that goes from 1 to n
SEQUENCE(1,size) * REGEXEXTRACT(BASE(SEQUENCE(2^size-1),2,size),REPT("(.)",size))


Then it performs a VLOOKUP on this array where the lookup column is the n x 1 array of values that goes from 1 to n and the result column is the input array (A1:A3).
VLOOKUP(binary_array,{idx,list},2,0)


After that we remove the errors and perform a row-by-row join with BYROW

And finally we SORT the result, first by the length, then in lexicographic order:
SORT(result,LEN(result),1,result,1)



This also works! If I could accept both answers I would but unfortunately I already used the other one and it got bonus points for being concise. I do appreciate your walkthrough of how your solution works though—thank you!

tested and the formula is working good for n=23
